# How to disable double tap for page-home on Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, browser

After wondering and getting annoyed by my phone sometimes just jumping to the beginning of a web Page, I finally found out that it's a new Feature of the internet browser. Double tapping on the top of the phone jumps to the top of a web page.

How can i disable this?

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S2 running ICS 4.0.3.

Answer (score 3):

Look under `Settings > Motion` for an option to disable double tap feature. I disabled the whole motion category.